# Fluent Validations showing old error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, fluentvalidation

I'm using fluent validation as described in the official documentation, with asp.net core 3.1 and swagger. My problem is that an old version of the error message is being added to the list before the current message (it was replaced about 100 commits ago). I have tried to rename the class, create a new one, check swagger configuration, tested in another computer and i don't know why the old message is still there.

```
using FluentValidation;

public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<Report> {

   public MyValidator() {

     RuleFor(report => report.FinalDate).NotNull().NotEmpty().When(report => report.Type.Equals("P")).WithMessage("A valid final date must be provided for this report");
   }
}
```

FinalDate is a string. After calling Validate() method, the ValidationResult errors contains "FinalDate should be valid" and  "A valid final date must be provided for this report".

Comment: Can you share the git repo? I have a feeling that the error comes from a merging conflict or some other git mistake. Can you search inside the whole repo code (not just the solution, the whole repo) for the string « FinalDate should be valid » and see if it appears somewhere else. Also, can you double check that you’re running your project on the right branch/repo, and that your branch doesn’t have anything staged or uncommitted that could cause this issue.

Comment: I'm definitely using the right branch. Maybe the problem is related with some sort of cache?

Answer (score 1):

What are you feeding into the validator? `report.FinalDate == null`, `report.Type == "P"`?

If that's the case you'll get 2 errors, 1 for `.NotNull()` and 1 for `.NotEmpty().When(report => report.Type.Equals("P")).WithMessage("A valid final date must be provided for this report")`

Unless you have `ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure` set elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it became clear why two error messages are generated.

Comment: But do you have any idea why .NotNull() is returning an old error message?

Comment: Are you overriding the default error message for the NotNull validator? I don't have enough data to answer that question. What I can say is that `.NotNull().NotEmpty().When(report => report.Type.Equals("P")).WithMessage("A valid final date must be provided for this report")` is only specifying a custom error message for the NotEmpty rule. The NotNull rule is using whatever the default is set to (I assume custom, as the actual default is something like `'Final Date' must not be empty.`). `WithErrorMessage` only applies to the rule it's attached to.

Comment: The first version of this rule was `.NotNull().When(report => report.Type.Equals("P")).WithMessage("FinalDate should be valid")`. Then, i changed the message to `"A valid final date must be provided for this report"`. After this, one person that is working with me added `.NotEmpty()`. I will remove `.NotNull()`, but i'm just curious about the message returned, it's definitely not the default (the message is in portuguese).